# Use AjaxControlToolKit in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution, ajax-control-tookit

I use following link for reference :

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/c995bcf6-b8c7-46de-af27-f54bc8d6e182#2b0f9864-fb6f-4ad2-aef4-1e51d41dfb60

But From where can i download AjaxControlToolKit version 2.0.0.0?

Comment: From Google , You can download AjaxControlToolKit

Comment: This is very old version of Ajax you may found on google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use Ajax Control Tool Kit in Sandbox solution to deploy in SharePoint Online (office 365).

Comment: This link may helps you  : -   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/sharepoint2010general/thread/f97e1494-c8df-4fac-b607-e353c64e29a7